# How to make a publicly shared file server

Tags: networking, server, file-sharing

I want to make a file server on Ubuntu that I can access from any Windows computer. I don't want a LAN server, I want a world wide server. I already fooled around with Samba and Apache2. (note: I am sort of a linux noob) Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use SCP.

For this, all you need to setup is `sshd` - the SSH server.

1. Install the `openssh-server` package.
2. **[Optional, but recommended]**: Change the SSH port:

   1. Copy `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_backup`
   2. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change the number in the line `Port 22` to some other one. This is because most SSH attacks target servers on Port `22`. Change it to a higher number.
3. **[Optional; use to access from machines outside your LAN]** Setup [static IP](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu), [port forwarding](http://portforward.com) (found in your router settings) and [dynamic DNS](http://noip.com).
4. Using the [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) client for Windows, you can now connect to your server and access files from anywhere. You also get Terminal access to your server (use [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)).

P.S. Anyone connecting will need to know your username and its password.

Comment: If I do that can I mount the server as a drive on my Windows computer?

Comment: Look at this SuperUser [answer](http://superuser.com/a/291801/542613).

Comment: Linux treats ports below 1024 as privileged ports, which can involve root privileges. if you really have to change your port number from 22 to a higher port number, it makes sense security-wise to also keep that new port number below 1024

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an simple http server like this,

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Not need apache.

Comment: OP wants a *file* server - **not** HTTP.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: when you exec this, if not index.html in current directory, the web show files list. of course download only.

Comment: I think you should add this to the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `proftpd-basic` package, You can download it from the repository. It is easy to configure, You can `blacklist` adresses, create `ftp users`, grant `privileges` to ftp access and to certain directories and still keep sshd closed.

Useful links and knowledge:

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/proftpd-basic